# Using print/puts for {} loop vs do end loop - ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm struggling to figure out/understand why I get the following syntax error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting '}'
odds.each { |x| x = x * 2 puts x }
                              ^
```

when running:

```
odds = [1,3,5,7,9]

odds.each { |x| x = x * 2 puts x }
```

This applies to print and puts. However when running:

```
odds.each do |x|
  x = x * 2
  puts x
end
```

I get the results I'm looking for. Therefore I cannot use print/puts with {} in this example even though I am able to in other circumstances.

Comment: `odds.each { |x| puts x*2 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Therefore I cannot use print/puts with {} in this example

You can.

```
odds.each { |x| x = x * 2; puts x }
                         ↑
# 2
# 6
# 10
# 14
# 18
```

It has nothing to do with `{}`, you just have to separate two statements with either newline or `;`.

Answer (score 0):

Your conclusion is wrong:

> Therefore I cannot use print/puts with {} in this example

Your mistake is that you are conflating several variables when testing your hypothesis. You should make sure that when you want to test something, you *only test that one thing* and not something else in addition to it.

In this particular case, your hypothesis is "I cannot use `puts` with `{`/`}`". However, when you test it, you change *two* things:

1. you change `do`/`end` to `{`/`}` and
2. you remove a linebreak

And now you get an error. However, since you changed two things at once, you *cannot know which of the two changes caused the error*. You assume that it was the first change, but you cannot know that. The only thing you know is that either the first or the second or the combination of the two changes caused the error.

You need to test those two changes separately:

Original code:

```
odds.each do |x|
  x = x * 2
  puts x
end
# works
```

Testing #1:

```
odds.each { |x|
  x = x * 2
  puts x
}
# works
```

Testing 21:

```
odds.each do |x| x = x * 2 puts x end
# SyntaxError
```

Aha! So, it turns out, it *wasn't* the curly braces after all! It was the linebreak!